# Comparing two strings in Haskell

Tags: string, function, haskell, boolean, compare

I came across a rather silly practice problem that was listed as easy, so I thought I could do it.  The premise is that a doctor must hear a patient say aah in order to give a diagnosis, but the aah from the patient must match the aah requested by the doctor.  If the doctor asks for aaaaah and the patient says ah, then no diagnosis can be given.  The Haskell program is supposed to read in a doctor and a patient aah in that order and return a Bool value for if a diagnosis may be given.  At first I thought they needed to be identical so this was my code:

```
seeDoctor :: String -> String -> Bool
seeDoctor a b = if a == b then True
                else False
```

However, I realized I wasn't following all the rules of the problem and it wasn't so simple.  The patient may say aah for longer than the doctor and return True, so "aah" "aaaah" returns True, as does "" "aaah" and "h" "aah", but "aaah" "ah" returns False. But even if the doctor doesn't include an 'h' in their aah, the patient must, so "a" "a" returns False, but my code would return True. So if the patient says anything, it must be the necessary number of 'a's followed by a single 'h' and no other characters.  You see, once I started trying the suggested test cases, I realized how little I understood.  Can I keep a count of 'a' in each string? How do I check for extra characters? Sorry this took a while to read. Thanks for making it this far.

Here is the exact question:

> "When we go to see a doctor, the doctor always asks us to say "aaah".
>   Sometimes, the doctor needs us to say "aaaaaah", but we are only able
>   to say "aaah". In that case, the doctor is unable to diagnose our
>   disease, because the 'a's in our "aaah" are fewer than his or her
>   requirements. Now, write a Haskell function called seeDoctor to judge
>   if the doctor can diagnose us with our "aah". The input of the
>   function consists of two strings. The first string is the "aaaah" the
>   doctor needs and the second string is the "aah" we are able to say.
>   Output "True" if our "aah" meets the requirements of the doctor, and
>   output "False" otherwise. The test should pass with a "True" only when
>   lowercase 'a's and 'h's are used, and each string contains a certain
>   number of 'a's followed by a single 'h'."

Comment: Can you post the request in verbatim? The way you describe it, is not very clear.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, both strings have the format `a*h*` (that's a regex, the `*` means *any number of the previous char), and the number of `a`'s and `h`s should be greater than or equal to the requested aahh?

Comment: What should be the output of `seeDoctor "foo" "aaaaaaaah"`?

Comment: I believe it should be False in that case, @MarkSeemann.

Comment: Why don't you just filter `'a'`s and `compare` their length..?

Comment: Also notice your first attempt is a common antipattern.  Any time you see `if p then True else False` you can just write `p`.  In this case you could even have written `seeDoctor = (==)` and not been explicit about the arguments.

Comment: Problem is https://open.kattis.com/problems/aaah

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're trying to learn Haskell, I'm not going to give you a solution, but I'll try to give you enough hints to enable you to put a function together yourself.

Strings are lists, so you can use the normal list functions from `Data.List`. For instance, `isSubsequenceOf` almost does what you need:

```
Prelude Data.List> isSubsequenceOf "aah" "aaah"
True
Prelude Data.List> isSubsequenceOf "aaaah" "aah"
False
```

If I interpret the problem description correctly, you should probably also check that only `a` and `h` are in the input strings, and that `h` is the last character.

In order to check that `h` is the last character, you could use the `last` function:

```
Prelude Data.List> last "aaaah"
'h'
Prelude Data.List> last "ah"
'h'
Prelude Data.List> last "foo"
'o'
```

Perhaps you'd also want to check the input for rogue characters, and return `False` if the two strings contain any other character than `a` and `h`...

```
Prelude Data.List> all (\c -> c == 'a' || c == 'h') "aaah"
True
Prelude Data.List> all (\c -> c == 'a' || c == 'h') "aaah!"
False
```

What would you do about a string like `"aha"`, though? I'll leave that as an exercise :)